# add group property in pandas within a chain (analogous to dplyr group_by - mutate in R)

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I would like to add some group properties as a new column to a pandas dataframe but without beaking the chain. I know this is possible in R using dplyr but I cannot get it to work in pandas.

The dplyr code would be (for adding max of column B per group in column A):

```
df %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(max = max(B)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   ... more operations
```

The only way I can get it to work in pandas is:

```
df['max'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')
```

but this requires a seperate line to assign the new column while I would like to do it inside a chain. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This article has info on method chaining, including pandas `pipe` command: https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.assign(max=df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max'))....more operations
```

Comment: Would this still work if there are operations in the chain before this one? In the dplyr equivalent the intermediate altered result is passed to the next step in the pipe but in your answer the df inside the 'assign' refers to the original unaltered dataframe right?

Comment: I use assign() all through my chains. Sequence of adding columns, after aggregations after reset index after before and after merge and concat

Comment: But if I for example first double the values in column B and then apply your 'assign' afterwards in the chain it gives the wrong results: df.assign(B = lambda row: 2*row.B).assign(max = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')). But if we also use a lambda for the second assign the problem seems to be solved...

Answer (score 1):

Now you are able to do it smoothly with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar)

```py
from datar import f
from datar.base import max
from datar.dplyr import group_by, mutate, ungroup

df >> \
   group_by(f.A) >> \
   mutate(max = max(f.B)) >> \
   ungroup() # >> 
   # ... more operations
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.